# In Sanity how to only use validation if boolean is set to true?

Tags: validation, sanity

In a current `document` group I'm trying to find a way to only allow validation when the boolean is set to `true`:

```
{
  title: 'Has the movie been released?',
  name: 'released',
  type: 'boolean',
  initialValue: true
}
```

fooBar.ts:

```
export default {
  title: 'Foo',
  name: 'foo',
  group: 'general',
  type: 'object',
  fields: [
    {
      title: 'Alpha',
      name: 'alphaBool',
      type: 'boolean',
      description: 'Random text',
      initialValue: false
    },
    {
      title: 'Alpha Location',
      name: 'alphaLoc',
      type: 'string',
      hidden: ({ parent }) => parent?.alphaBool !== true,
      validation: Rule => Rule.required()
    }
  ]
};
```

but this current implemented approach throws a required error even though it might be set to `false`. I've tried to see if I could pass down either `parent` or `document` from `validation` so I could attempt to get the value of `alphaBool` but they both show `undefined`:

```
validation: (rule, parent, document) => console.log(rule, parent, document)
```

but I'm allowed to see `parent` and `document` objects in `hidden`.

### Research

- [Conditional fields](https://www.sanity.io/docs/conditional-fields)
- [Field Groups](https://www.sanity.io/docs/field-groups)
- [Conditional validation of string](https://www.sanity.io/schemas/conditional-validation-of-string-based-on-boolean-6944429d)
- [Boolean](https://www.sanity.io/docs/boolean-type)
- [Now you see them, now you don’t. Introducing Conditional Fields.](https://www.sanity.io/blog/now-you-see-them-now-you-don-t-introducing-conditional-fields)
- [Validation](https://www.sanity.io/docs/validation)
- [Optional validation for hidden fields](https://www.sanity.io/schemas/optional-validation-for-hidden-fields-439d0ab8)

In Sanity 2.35.0 how can I run validation only if the boolean value is set to `true`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understand your question, you can use custom validations for this.

**Example:**

```
{
 title: 'Alpha',
 name: 'alphaBool',
 type: 'boolean',
 description: 'Random text',
 initialValue: false
},
{
  title: 'Alpha Location',
  name: 'alphaLoc',
  type: 'string',
  hidden: ({ parent }) => parent?.alphaBool !== true,
  validation: (Rule) => Rule.custom((value, { document: { alphaBool } }) => {
    return alphaBool && !value ? "Field required" : true
  })
}
```

With `Rule.custom`, you can access the value of the field and the `context` object of the document. In this example, if `alphaBool` is set to `true` and the current field's value is an empty string, then it will throw a `Field required` validation message. If `alphaBool` is `false`, it will not validate anything.

Comment: so the only way to access `document` it is through Rule's `custom`?

Comment: It seems that's the case, since `validation` property's function only takes one argument which is the rule itself.